# Material FloatingActionButton inside CoordinatorLayout is not showing in the design preview window

Tags: material-design, floating-action-button, androidx

I am using material FloatingActionButton inside CoordinatorLayout with androidx libraries, but my design window is not showing anything. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main content -->

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```